# EyeBall Camera OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, trigonometry

I'm currently trying to create an EyeBall view camera in OpenGL

If I remember properly, an EyeBall Camera is a camera that can move around an objet but without using the Euler angle. So its just a camera rotating around a point.

I was wondering how I could do it by only using Trigo. Right now, I have a weird camera that isn't working at all !

```
int t_Camera::CameraMouvement()
{
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
    {
        m_ValueToRotate.x = m_ValueToRotate.x - 0.1;
        m_ValueToRotate.z = m_ValueToRotate.z - 0.1;
        m_Mouvement = 1;
    }

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
    {
        m_ValueToRotate.x = m_ValueToRotate.x + 0.1;
        m_ValueToRotate.z = m_ValueToRotate.z + 0.1;
        m_Mouvement = 1;
    }

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
    {
        m_ValueToRotate.y = m_ValueToRotate.y + 0.1;
        m_ValueToRotate.z = m_ValueToRotate.z + 0.1;
        m_Mouvement = 1;
    }

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
    {
        m_ValueToRotate.y = m_ValueToRotate.y - 0.1;
        m_ValueToRotate.z = m_ValueToRotate.z - 0.1;
        m_Mouvement = 1;
    }

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space))
    {
        m_ValueToScale.x = m_ValueToScale.x + 0.1;
        m_ValueToScale.y = m_ValueToScale.y + 0.1;
        m_ValueToScale.y = m_ValueToScale.y + 0.1;
        m_Mouvement = 1;
    }

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::LShift))
    {
        m_ValueToScale.x = m_ValueToScale.x - 0.1;
        m_ValueToScale.y = m_ValueToScale.y - 0.1;
        m_ValueToScale.x = m_ValueToScale.x - 0.1;
        m_Mouvement = 1;
    }

    return m_Mouvement;
}

void t_Math::CreateLookAt(glm::mat4& InMatrix, sf::Vector3f& pointToFix,   sf::Vector3f& valueToRotate, sf::Vector3f& valueToScale)
{
    InMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);

    const glm::vec3 constObjetMiddle = glm::vec3(pointToFix.x, pointToFix.y, pointToFix.z);

    const GLfloat x_Point = cos(valueToRotate.x * (valueToScale.x*10)) * sin(valueToRotate.z * (valueToScale.z*10));
    const GLfloat y_Point = cos(valueToRotate.y * (valueToScale.y*10)) * sin(valueToRotate.z * (valueToScale.z*10));
    const GLfloat z_Point = cos(valueToRotate.y * (valueToScale.y*10)) * sin(valueToRotate.x * (valueToScale.x*10));

    InMatrix = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(x_Point, y_Point, z_Point), constObjetMiddle, glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
}
```

My Goal is that by pressing the controls (W-A-S-D) you can control the rotation around the objet and by using Space and Shift, you can control the zoom on the objet.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: What exactly do you expect that code to be doing?

Comment: I expect it to create a EyeBall Camera using the LookAt GLM function. By that, I'm trying to use Sin and Cos to calculate the 3D coord of the camera.

Comment: Sounds like you want a classic 'trackball' or 'arcball' implementation using quaternions.

Comment: You can't really describe what you wanna do in terms of "a camera that can move around an objet but without using the Euler angle". Defining by saying that it doesn't use one specific mathematical tool doesn't indicate what you want it to do